# What are the origins of the song *A Soft Spot* played by Barry Haris at Tokyo in 1976?

Tags: history, jazz, piano

In [Barry Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Harris)' [live performance at Tokyo in 1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_in_Tokyo_(Barry_Harris_album)), he plays a song called *A Soft Spot*. I was wondering about the origins of this song and I would be happy if anyone can find any other jazz recordings of this song.

Here is him playing the song:

> [*Barry Harris Trio 1976 - A Soft Spot*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6vkbTqsblE)
>
> Artists: Barry Harris (piano), Sam Jones (bass), Leroy Williams (drums)
>   Album: *The Barry Harris Trio / Complete Live In Tokyo 1976*
>   Recorded: Live at Tokyo, April 12, 1976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The South African born jazz pianist Liane Fainsinger recorded ["A Soft Spot"](https://lianefainsinger.com/my-music/) on her own album of the same name.
According to her bio she participated in many masterclasses with Barry Harris, so it's not unlikely that he is in fact the composer and that she got the music directly from him.
The song is based on the harmonies to George Gershwin's "'S Wonderful" ([source](http://www.murielgrossmann.com/wp-content/uploads/NYCJR.pdf)).

Comment: Yes, on the website you gave, it says it was composed by Barry Harris

Comment: @Haversine I know it said so on the website, but you can't always trust everything you read on the net :)

Comment: eh i think it's good enough :)